# try-catch-finally as expression

Tags: kotlin, try-catch

I am stuck with an exercise on hyperskill.org at try-catch-finally exception(exercise: Parting words).
Try-catch-finally should be used as an expression. In the "try" block an input string is required to check if it consists of two words separated by a space. If not(there's only one word given), an exception is thrown in the "catch" block. Otherwise the code in the "try" block should be evaluated. How can it be achived?

```
fun pepTalk(name: String) : String {
    val array = name.split(" ").toTypedArray()
    val firstName = array[0]
    val secondName = array[1]
    return "Don't lose the towel, traveler $firstName $secondName!"
}
// do not change the function above

fun main() {
    val name = readLine()!!

    val advice: String = try{name ????}    
                catch (e: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) { "nameless one" }
                finally { println("Good luck!") }
    println(pepTalk(advice))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `pepTalk` inside the `try` block as it can throw an exception.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val name = readLine()!!

    val advice = 
        try {
            pepTalk(name)
        }    
        catch (e: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) { 
            "Don't lose the towel, nameless one."
        }
        finally { 
            println("Good luck!") 
        }
    println(advice)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I dont really see why it throw an exception when there is one string passed. Is it because the demiliter is missing from the string passed?

Comment: From one string, do you mean one word? The error is because after splitting with the delimiter, you have only one string in your `array` and when you try to access `array[1]`, it throws the exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question?